# Randomly run "a few" tests with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am working on a numeric calculation application and have two sets of "unit" tests. "Fast" tests which run in < 10ms per tests and "long" tests which take several minutes per test. Let's assume that this is necessary here, for example, when testing an example for the integration of a differential equation. You probably would not see something like this in tests for regular applications or webdev or other things. In numerics, you sometimes have to create relatively large grids (arrays) on which you perform calculations and this takes time.

I am using automation using gitlab (but this should be generalizablet to some extent). The problem is that I cannot run all long tests everytime I push some code since this would take tens of hours. The idea is therefore to always run all "fast" tests and run *some* long tests.

Is there a way to do this using pytest? For example, let pytest run tests for 2 hours and then mark all remaining long tests as "expected failure". Or alternatively, let pytest run a fixed number of tests.

The tests which do get run would have to be chosen in a completely random order so that ideally, if this procedure is repeated several times, all tests will have (almost certainly) been executed at least once.

Answer (score 2):

The big piece that you are missing at present is a database of historic, typical elapsed times to run individual tests.

With that in hand, it should be straightforward to auto generate test suites that invoke a suitable selection of tests in random order. Impose a budget of 100 seconds elapsed time or whatever, and then one “long“ test at random.

Storing a permutation of long tests will let you conveniently iterate through them at each commit, avoiding duplication.

If building a large grid is the dominant cost for large tests, then group several related tests sharing a grid, so you can run N-1 of them “for free” once you’ve paid the setup cost.

Consider running two separate CI/CD tasks, short + long, so after a commit you get feedback at, perhaps, the 1- and 6- minute marks.

Comment: I could probably write a pytest plugin for that. I think a simple sqlite3 database could be used to make the "state" of all the permutations persistent, which could then be uploaded as an artifact and re-downloaded at the next run.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `pytest_collection_modifyitems()` hook to delete some of those tests that are mark as "long". For example, in the following module, `test_1` is unmarked (assumed to be fast) and `test_2` is marked with long:

```py
import pytest

def test_1():
    pass

@pytest.mark.long
def test_2():
    pass
```

Here is how we can implement the hook:

```py
# conftest.py
import random

import pytest


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(
    session: pytest.Session, config: pytest.Config, items: list[pytest.Item]
):
    # Find indices of those with mark=long
    indices = [
        index
        for index, item in enumerate(items)
        if list(item.iter_markers(name="long"))
    ]

    # Removes 3/4 number of tests
    removal_count = len(indices) * 3 // 4

    # Delete
    to_be_deleted = random.sample(indices, removal_count)
    to_be_deleted.sort(reverse=True)
    for index in to_be_deleted:
        del items[index]
```

Notes

1. The [doc for pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#std-hook-pytest_collection_modifyitems) does not say much, all we need to know is we need to delete tests from `items`
2. `indices` contains all the list indices of those tests that are marked with "long"
3. In this case, we are removing 3/4 number of long tests. In other word, we are running only 1/4 of them
4. `to_be_deleted` contains a list of indices to delete. Note: this list must be sorted in descending order so we can delete the correct items

## Update

Instead of deleting tests from `items`, an alternative is to skip them. Replace the line that reads:

```py
        del items[index]
```

with

```py
        items[index].add_marker(pytest.mark.skip(reason="Not selected this time"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As I had hinted at in my comment to @J_H's answer, I have now written a plugin for this purpose: [`pytest-samples`](https://github.com/devds96/pytest-samples). As the name suggests, you can use it to run a few tests until some timeout expires. You can also choose to either randomize the test order each time so that the first few tests that will actually run will be different each time ("nostate mode") or you can provide a path to an SQLite database in which information regarding previously succeeded tests will be stored to put them last in the test queue ("stateful mode").

The default run time is 50min, but you can change that using a command line flag. After the timeout expires, all remaining tests will be marked as "skipped". Since it is only checked after each test whether the timeout has expired, you should plan in some extra time for the shutdown of the test session when you use this plugin in some CI setting such as github actions.